# How can I automate downloading web database files and save them to the company's network with Python, without using restricted libraries?

Tags: python, excel, vba, mouse, recorder

I have a web database, which every day at work I have to go and download manually, then save it in a folder on the company's network.

There are 4 files and my question is simple: how can I automate this task? It seems simple but doing this every day is a real pain... In my company, we have restrictions on using some python libraries, such as pyautogui etc...

So I would need a simple suggestion, which I'll try to learn how to do. Thanks :)

Pyautogui, python libraries

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it. Of course, you need to customize the code for your specific use case.

```
# download from web
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Utility/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://cdr.ffiec.gov/public/PWS/DownloadBulkData.aspx')
listproduct = ['Call Reports -- Single Period',
               'Call Reports -- Balance Sheet, Income Statement, Past Due -- Four Periods']


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()  
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.default_directory": r"C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\my_desktop\\", "download.prompt_for_download": False, "download.directory_upgrade": True, "safebrowsing.enabled": True}) 

 
for product in listproduct:
    try:
        Weblistbox=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"ListBox1")))
        select=Select(Weblistbox)
        select.select_by_visible_text(product)
        print("Product {} is selected".format(product))
    
        for year in range(0,4):
            datedropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "DatesDropDownList")))
            select = Select(datedropdown)
            select.select_by_index(year)
            datedropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "DatesDropDownList")))
            select = Select(datedropdown)
            print("DateOrYear {} is selected".format(select.first_selected_option.text))
            WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'Download_0'))).click()
    except:
        print('out of range...')
```